# How can I add days and months in the field?

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk

1. using `if` statement if field one + 1 day equal field two.
2. using `if` statement if field one + 1 month  equal field two.

I have this input

```
09-11-2013    09-12-2013
10-02-2013    10-02-2013
26-10-2013    27-10-2013
12-01-2013    12-02-2013
22-02-2013    23-02-2013
```

I used this code but it works with years only:

```
awk '{if ($1+1==$2) print }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `mktime` funktin in `awk`
With it you can convert date to seconds so it be easy to compare.

This prints how many days there are between `$1` and `$2`

```
awk '{split($1, sd, "-");split($2, ed, "-");print $0,(mktime(ed[3] s ed[2] s ed[1] s 0 s 0 s 0)-mktime(sd[3] s sd[2] s sd[1] s 0 s 0 s 0))/86400}' s=' ' file
09-11-2013    09-12-2013 30
10-02-2013    10-02-2013 0
26-10-2013    27-10-2013 1
12-01-2013    12-02-2013 31
22-02-2013    23-02-2013 1
```

---

Her it prints `1` of its one day, and `2` if its one month.
It take in count that February may have `28` or `29` days

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        arr="31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31"
        split(arr, month, ",")
        x=0}
        {
        split($1, sd, "-")
        split($2, ed, "-")
        t=(mktime(ed[3] s ed[2] s ed[1] s 0 s 0 s 0)-mktime(sd[3] s sd[2] s sd[1] s 0 s 0 s 0))/86400
        month[2]=sd[3]%4==0?29:28
        }
    t==month[sd[2]+0] {x=2}
    t==1 {x=1}
        {print $0,x
        x=0}
    ' s=' ' file
09-11-2013    09-12-2013 2
10-02-2013    10-02-2013 0
26-10-2013    27-10-2013 1
12-01-2013    12-02-2013 2
22-02-2013    23-02-2013 1
```